# scala split on capturing group

Tags: regex, scala, split

I am trying to split a string on only the capturing group of a regex, but I appear to be splitting on the entire match.

I would like to split `hi|my~~|~|name is bob` on `|`'s preceded by an zero or any even number of `~`'s

So my expected output is `Array(hi, my~~, ~|name is bob)`

I am using the regex `"(?<!~)(?:~~)*(\\|)"`

But `"hi|my~~|~|name is bob".split("(?<!~)(?:~~)*(\\|)")` is returning `Array[String] = Array(hi, my, ~|name is bob)` because it is splitting on the entire `~~|` after `my` instead of just the `|` that is preceeded by `~~`.

For example compare:

```
scala> "(?<!~)(?:~~)*(\\|)".r.findAllIn("hi|my~~|~|name is bob").foreach(println)
|
~~|
```

to

```
scala> "(?<!~)(?:~~)*(\\|)".r.findAllIn("hi|my~~|~|name is bob").matchData foreach { m => println(m.group(1)) }
|
|
```

**EDIT**:

Some context and clarification:

I am trying to serialize a list of strings into a single string separated by `|`. I cannot guarantee that `|` (or any character for that matter) will not appear in an individual string.

To achieve the desired functionality I want to escape all occurrences of `|`. I have chosen the `~` as my escape character. Before I can escape `|` I need to escape `~`.

Once I have escaped everything I can join the list with `|` to get a single string representing my original list of strings.

Then later to parse the single string back into the original list I need to split only on unescaped `|`'s. I have to be careful because something like `~~|` is actually an unescaped pipe even though it contains `~|`. This is because the escape character is itself escaped, which means it was just a "tilda" in one of my original strings and is not meant to function as an "escape". In other words I had a string ending in `~`, and it is now escaped into `~~` and joined with the next string in the list by a '|'.

OK, so if my initial list of strings is `["hi","my~","|name is bob"]` I will first escape all `~`'s to get  `["hi","my~~","|name is bob"]`. Now I will escape all `|`'s to get  `["hi","my~~","~|name is bob"]`, and finally I will join with `|` to get the single string:

"`hi|my~~|~|name is bob"`

Now if I want to reverse this I need to first split on unescaped `|`'s, which is any `|` preceded by zero or an even number of `~`'s. So if I can achieve this with my regex (so far I am capturing this correctly in my capturing group, but I just don't know how to apply only the group and not the full `~~|` match for example to the split), then I will get `["hi","my~~","~|name is bob"]`. Now I simply unescape my `~`'s, unescape my `|`, and I have arrived back at my original input:

`["hi","my~","|name is bob"]`

Comment: I don't understand the expected output: Array(hi, my~~, ~|name is bob). Why are the separators part of it? Why not Array(hi, my, name is bob)?

Comment: The | in my expected output is not a separator. It is a | that was in my initial input, and that needed to be escaped so I didn't confuse it with a separator. Please see my edit for more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need all the `~`s to be part of the look-behind group, since `split` splits on the *whole* match of the regex, not just a group of it, even if that group is a non-capturing group.  A simpler example:

```
"asdf" split "(?:s)" //Array(a, df)
```

The look-behind group is not part of the match, so you want to put your prefix criteria in there.  Basically, you need to wrap your solution in another look-behind group.  Ideally, you'd want:

```
"""(?<=(?<!~)(~~)*)\|"""
```

But unfortunately Java doesn't support look-behind groups of arbitrary length.  As a workaround, you can do:

```
"""(?<=(?<!~)(~~){0,10})\|"""
```

Which would work for even number of `~`s as long as there are 20 or fewer.  You could increase 10 if this is a problem.

If the nested look-behinds are confusing, you can also use the equivalent:

```
"""(?<![^~]~(~~){0,10})\|"""
```

Comment: `"hi|my~~|~|name is bob" split """(?<=(~~){0,10})\|"""` yields `Array(hi, my~~, ~, name is bob)` not `Array(hi, my~~, ~|name is bob)`.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you for taking the time to get this working.